Upper cabinets vs floating shelves in kitchen? Why can one hold more weight than another?
Tldr at bottom
Hi, I'm doing a full kitchen remodel. I previously had 2 kitchen cabinets that were super normal. No one thought it was weird that they would consistently hold cast iron pans, ceramic dishware, and other heavy stuff.
I'm looking to replace them with something I could make myself. I've done a couple of tests and I feel confident that I could build a floating shelf bracket and box to cover it using 2x4, 2x2 and nice 1/4in plywood. These shelves would be 16in deep which is 2in shorter than the cabinets I previously had. They will be screwed into studs every 16 inches (2 offset screws per stud per shelf with 3 shelves per wall (so 6 screws per stud)).
Everyone and their mother is suddenly telling me that these shelves will fall down and break all my stuff and be a big problem for me... Is that true?? Why?? It seems to me that they should be able to hold the same amount of stuff as the cabinets but I will admit I'm not someone with a lot of experience.
Tldr: is it true that upper kitchen cabinets can hold more weight than floating shelves of the same depth? Why or why not? Is there a way to make floating shelves for upper kitchen cabinets work safely while still holding into storage capacity?

A cabinet under load is more likely to want to slide down the wall, and shears against the screws holding it up. The vertical height of the cabinet fights the tendency of a load to rotate forward off the wall while wanting to fall, and the screws themselves can hold up the cabinet.
A floating shelf does not have much vertical height, so the rotating force will be much greater. A proper shelf bracket provides the vertical component required to keep the shelf from wanting to rotate and come back under control of the mounting screws.
If you're making essentially a low flat box, and screwing the back of the box into the studs, that's probably not enough to hold heavy loads up. The screws may simply pull out of the studs when the shelf rotates forward under load.
A floating shelf will be quite able to hold up heavy weights. It all depends on the bracket used to hold the shelf up.
There are hidden L-shaped shelf brackets where the vertical part goes inside the wall and screw sideways into the studs within the wall, and the horizontal part pokes out of the wall for the shelves to attach to. Try a web-search on "concealed shelf brackets".

Agree that you want something beefy holding stuff up. For example (though not an endorsement): https://ironsupports.com/products/floating-countertop-wall-bracket

The rotating force is the same (given equal weight of contents), it's that the rotational resistance of the cabinet is greater due to its height. :)

Depending on the design, a floating shelf can hold 40-50 lb per stud it is attached to.
Assuming that you have a 4' shelf with 16" studs that give you 120-150 lbs of weight your shelf can support. Or 2.5 lbs per inch of wall space.
Assuming your cabinet has adjustable shelves (very popular now). Metal clips in a cabinet can hold 25 lbs per clip. The plastic clips can hold 10 lbs per clip.
If your cabinet uses plastic clips, then a 24 inch cabinet shelf can support 40 pounds, giving you 80 pounds across 4' of shelf or ~1/2 the weight of the floating shelf.
Using metal clips each cabinet shelf in a 24 inch cabinet can hold 100 lbs, Which gives 200 lbs across a 4' span. 33% more per inch of shelf.
Smaller Cabinets can hold more weight per inch of shelf.
If your cabinet doesn't have adjustable shelves it can support more weight. Don't have the numbers off the top of my head and it depends a lot on the construction of the cabinet.
The wall cabinet can hold ~ 300 - 600 lbs (depending on the manufacturer) low number is for mdf, high number is plywood.
TLDR:
It depends on your construction.
A floating shelf can hold 33% less weight per inch of shelving space then some types of cabinets, and can hold 2x more than other types of cabinets. In other words it sits in middle, and should be fine.
As an aside I have seen a couple of kitchens using floating shelves, and didn't notice any sagging... It's fine.
